# Changing Excel columns & rows , from vertical to horizontal order

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Currently I have a list of computers with their hardware specifications in a vertially order, this should be changed to horizontally. What I have is:

```
|    A    |    B     |     C     |
| PC-NAME | HDD-SIZE | CPU Count |
|_Test-PC_|__100GB___|_____6_____|
|_Test-PC2|__200GB___|_____3_____|
```

what I need is:

```
|     A     |    B    |    C    |
| PC-NAME   |_Test-PC_|_Test-PC2|
| HDD-SIZE  |__100GB__|___200GB_|
| CPU Count |____6____|___3_____|
```

It can be on a different spot on the Excel sheet, doesn't even have to be one the same sheet. 
I tried to drag the formula horizontally to receive "A1,A2,A3" but dragging will always increase the alphabet meaning A1,B1,C1... 
How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your table is **square** you can:

- copy the table
- click on another cell
- PasteSpecial > Transpose

[image]

Comment: There's no need for the source range to be square if you're pasting somewhere else. If the source is m columns by n rows, transposing as you paste will give you an n columns by m rows range. In your example, if you select the 3 x 2 range `1`, `2`, `3`; `4`, `5`, `6` and transpose it, you'll get the 2 x 3 range `1`, `4`; `2`, `5`; `3`, `6`.

Comment: @blm  .............Thanks! ......................

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy the table.
2. Select the top-left cell of where you want to paste the result.
3. Right-click the selected cell and choose `Paste Special...`
4. Check the `Transpose` option and click OK.

   [image]